# I am not able to connect mongoose to mongodb on my local database,

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using the below code:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose/');
const db = mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fruitsDB");
```

However, I am getting the below error

```
$ node app.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../../connection'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\dell\Desktop\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js
- C:\Users\dell\Desktop\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\index.js     
- C:\Users\dell\Desktop\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\dell\Desktop\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\index.js
- C:\Users\dell\Desktop\FruitsProject\app.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dell\enter code hereDesktop\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:7:28)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
```

I have seen so many questions based on this topic but I couldn't be able to connect my mongoose to my database.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Quite obvious, you misspelled the module.

Comment: yeah, that was my mistake to put "/" with mongoose but after that it is also not working.

Comment: const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fruitsDB");

Comment: Check `C:\Users\dell\Desktop\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js` exists...if not I don't know how it missed..but try to re-install the `mongoose` package and check

Comment: It exists but with name: connection.js.DELETE.80c67e387a3ee9dab69282f7aa28483b

Comment: Thank you PRATHEESH, i just uninstalled module and then reinstalled mongoose.

Comment: If it's working now, you should mark this question as answered. I copied PRATHEESH PC's comment into an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As @pratheesh-pc mentioned in a comment above. You should check for the '../../connection' file in the mongoose package in your node_modules. If it is missing, you should first try to re-install the package.

You can do so with `rm -rf node_modules && npm i`.

Comment: yeah, i reinstalled the mongoose module and it worked. Thank you

Comment: If this worked for you, please mark it as closed so other's can find it.